# How to achieve correctly the typesetting of $\bigwedge^\prime$ in display style?

Tags: displaystyle

I want to achieve `\bigwedge'`

[image: bigwedge1]

in display style.

However, `\[\bigwedge'\]` gives me naturally

[image: bigwedge2]

The first approach I tried is to convert it in text style, but it becomes smaller than it was in display style:

[image: bigwedge3]

(for `\[\bigwedge T \le \bigwedge S \implies \textstyle{\bigwedge'}\]`)

How could I achieve `bigwedge'` in display style without altering its size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\bigwedge` is a large math operator and is therefore sensitive to `\limits` and `\nolimits`. If you have no other stuff to put above or below it you can use `\bigwedge\nolimits'`. If you have other indices you might be interested in the `\sideset` command from `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document} 

\[
\bigwedge\nolimits' \qquad
\bigwedge\nolimits'_{i=1} \qquad
\sideset{}{'}\bigwedge_{i=1}^{n}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you put `\bigwedge` into curly braces it works as expected. Another approach would be to insert a small positive space in between `\bigwedge` and `'`. This would mess up the height of the operator, because it wouldn't be related to `\bigwedge` anymore.

---

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[\bigwedge^{\prime}\] % Doesn't work; equivalent to '-syntax
\[\bigwedge T \le \bigwedge S \implies {\bigwedge}'\]
\[\bigwedge\,'\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem with `{\bigwedge}'` is that is messes up spacing: enclosing a symbol (or subformula) in `{...}` turns it into a `\mathord`.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that! However i don't see any difference between the `{...}'` and `\sideset`-solutions in our screenshots.
Your solution is the "right one", while mine is faster to type i guess.

Comment: True, no difference in the screenshots. But try to add some symbols left or right and you'll notice. E.g. `{\bigwedge}'T` vs `\bigwedge\nolimits'T`.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @campa what you say is true but (depending on the meaning the OP wants) maybe `{}` as a mathord is the right thing. The bigwedge is an operator applied to T and S but (apparently) the primed version is not an operator but a self standing term to the right of the arrow so maybe the `{}` version is more natural. Not sure.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Could be, you're right.